# According to Id only working 1 HTML form HTML/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here i'm using this coding for Add & Update form.In here Add & Update uses same form 2 Html parts. But in here there's a few errors.

> 1.Notice: Undefined index: Id in C:\wamp\www\MyProject\admin\add.php on line 28
>
> The **big issue** is according to   if ($id == 0) { in Line 31.Only working 1 form When i use if($id==0) then only working Add Part & when i use ($id != 0 ) then only working Edit Part.

Here i paste whole code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/multi-line-button.css"/>

</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['Id']; < ---- LINE 28
   //if(isset($_GET['Id']))

    if ($id == 0) {    <-- Line 31

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            include('config.php');
            $Title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Title"]);
            $Description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
            $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
            $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
            $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
            $DateTime = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
            $Category = $_POST["select_category"];

            if (substr($imageType, 0, 5) == "image") {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `News` VALUES('','$Title','$imageName','$Description','$imageData','$Category',1,'$DateTime',1)");
                //echo "<a href=list.php>View List</a>";
                echo "<a href=list.php><img src=http://localhost:8090/MySite/img/success.gif /><span>View List</span></a>";
            } else {
                echo "Only images are allowed!";
            }
            ?>
              
              //This is the First HTML Form it uses ADD function

            <form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                <div class="OuterWrapper" background-color:white; >
                     <div class="row" id="wrapper" >
                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:5%">
                            Title
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:5%">
                            <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            Description
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            Image
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <input type="file" name="image">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            Category
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <select name="select_category" class="form-control">
                                <option value="" >-- Select Category --</option>
                                <option value="1">What's New</option>
                                <option value="2">The Time For a Program</option>
                                <option value="3">Event Information</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-left:28%">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

                        </div>
                        <div>



                            </form>

    <?php
} else {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("halftimedb") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT Id,Title,description,Image,Category from News WHERE Id='" . $id . "'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    ?>


                              //Here is Second HTML Form It uses EDIT Function


                            <form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                <div class="OuterWrapper" background-color:white; >
                                     <div class="row" id="wrapper" >
                                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:5%">
                                            Title
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-top:5%">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="Title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" >
                                            <input type="text" name="Title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            Description
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            Image
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                                            <div>
                                                <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row[3]) ?>' />
                                            </div>  
                                            <input type="file" name="image">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                                            Category
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-3">

                                            <select name="select_category" class="form-control">

                                                <option value="0" <?php if ($row[4] == '0') echo 'selected'; ?> >-- Select Category --</option>
                                                <option value="1"  <?php if ($row[4] == '1') echo 'selected'; ?>>What's New</option>
                                                <option value="2" <?php if ($row[4] == '2') echo 'selected'; ?>>The Time For a Program</option>
                                                <option value="3" <?php if ($row[4] == '3') echo 'selected'; ?>>Event Information</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-3" style="margin-left:28%">
                                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">

                                        </div>
                                        <div>



                                            </form>
    <?php
    //var_dump($row);
    //$Title_save = $_POST['Title'];
    //$description_save = $_POST['description'];
    //$Category  = $_POST["select_category"];
    //mysql_query("UPDATE News SET Title ='$Title_save', Description ='$description_save' WHERE Id = '$id'")
    //or die(mysql_error()); 
    //echo "Succesfully Updated!";
    //header("Location: list.php");
    }
  }
    ?>
                                    </body>
                                    </html>
```

This is a huge code.I paste all code for easy to understand my issue.I'm anewbie to php.Can you please help me to solve this.?

Comment: May I politely share the tip that you would want to wean off from `mysql_query` as this is being phrased out as 'old'.  Going for mysql PDO will save your headache especially in future. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :
use `isset()`

```
$id = isset($_REQUEST['Id']) ?  $_REQUEST['Id'] : ''; 



 if(!empty($id))  {

    if ($id == 0) {    

     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include('config.php');
        $Title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["Title"]);
        $Description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);
        $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
        $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);
        $DateTime = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
        $Category = $_POST["select_category"];

        if (substr($imageType, 0, 5) == "image") {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `News` VALUES('','$Title','$imageName','$Description','$imageData','$Category',1,'$DateTime',1)");
            //echo "<a href=list.php>View List</a>";
            echo "<a href=list.php><img src=http://localhost:8090/MySite/img/success.gif /><span>View List</span></a>";
        } else {
            echo "Only images are allowed!";
        }
     }

  } 
}
```

Comment: if(!empty(id) is replace to Line 31 ?

Comment: It's quite curious phenomenon, why all software engineers always read no more than two first lines from the question.

Comment: @Sonic99: do you wanted to solve your undefined index notices? if yes then check my answer it should remove notices now

Comment: @AwladLiton Yes Undefined Index issue solved BUT still 2nd issue not solved.

Comment: And even more curious one, who is upvoting a post that doesn't answer the the question at all. And even doesn't make any sense by itself.